# Magento Admin Page White Screen

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, php-5.4

I'm getting an interesting issue. The frontend of my website loads fine, however when I try to navigate to:

domain.com/index.php/admin

I get a white page. I have enabled debugging mode and it displays this error:

```
Array
(
    [type] => 2
    [message] => include(): Failed opening '/var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/sub-domain.domain.co.uk/includes/src/__adminhtml.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/sub-domain.domain.co.uk/includes/src:.:')
    [file] => /var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/sub-domain.domain.co.uk/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php
    [line] => 108
)
```

What's also interesting is that the file it's referencing (__adminhtml.php) doesn't exist in that directory:

[image: Missing File]

Any suggestions here?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the compiler.

Edit `includes/config.php`

And comment out the two highlighted lines like shown here:

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/includes/config.php#L28-L29

*** EDIT ***

---

Edit `.htaccess` file in the root of your installation of Magento and enable Developer mode. Add this at the end of the file:

`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Also, edit `index.php` and uncomment `#ini_set('display_errors', 1);`.

This should show an error instead of a WSOD (White Screen Of Death).  If it doesn't check `var/log/` and view the contents of `exception.log` or `system.log`. If nothing is relevant there, then proceed to look into your web server's error logs.

With that said however, the fact that the fatal exception has the path `includes/src/` in it means that the Compiler is enabled and is trying to include a file that doesn't exist.

If you can SSH into your server give this a try, simply change into the directory of your magento installation:

**NOTE:** *If you do not have SSH access simply renaming the `includes` to something else like `includes.unused` will work via FTP.*

**Check current compilation status**

`php -f shell/compiler.php -- state`

Which should output something like:

```
Compiler Status:          Enabled
Compilation State:        Compiled
Collected Files Count:    6042
Compiled Scopes Count:    4
```

**To Disable Magento compilation**

`php -f shell/compiler.php -- disable`

Which should output something like:

> Compiler include path disabled

**To Clear all compiled files**

`php -f shell/compiler.php -- clear`

Which should output something like:

> Compilation successfully cleared

**Ensure that compiler is disabled now by checking its status**

`php -f shell/compiler.php -- state`

Which should output something like:

```
Compiler Status:                  Disabled
Compilation State:                Not
Compiled Collected Files Count:   0 
Compiled Scopes Count:            0
```

After confirming your compiler is disabled, remove the entire contents of the `/var/cache/` folder with: `rm -Rf var/cache/`.

If you are not using files for caching (check your `app/etc/local.xml` file for details on what caching mechanism is being used) then restarting Redis, memcache, etc. may help flush any cached data for the compiler.  You can also revert it to the file system by commenting out any cache nodes for an alternative caching system like Redis, memcache, DB, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But after disabling the compiler and opening the config.php file, those two lines of code are already commented out.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I've managed to get the file back via clearing/disabling/compiling the compiler. I'm now however getting this issue: `Array
(
    [type] => 64
    [message] => Cannot redeclare class Mage_Admin_Model_Session
    [file] => /var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/sub-domain.co.uk/includes/src/__adminhtml.php
    [line] => 504
)`

Comment: Since finding this new error, I've tried to comment/remove every class that it cannot redeclare, one by one.. Only to find that by the time I've commented them all out and refreshed the admin page, it gives no error whatsoever. Just a white page.

Comment: Updated Answer.